# Strategies to detect and delete cluttering aggregations of GPS points?

Tags: algorithm, gps, tracking

my problem is that I have a large set of GPS tracks from different GPS loggers used in cars. When not turned off these cheap devices log phantom movements even if standing still:

[image]

As you can see in the image above, about a thousand points get visualized in a kind of congestion. Now I want to remove all of these points so that the red track coming from the left ends before the jitter starts.
My approach is to "draw" two or three circles around each point in the track, check how many other points are located within these circles and check the ratio:

`(#points / covered area) > threshold?`

[image]

If the threshold exceeds a certain ratio (purple circles), I could delete all points within. So: easy method, but has huge disadvantages, e.g. computation time, deleting "innocent" tracks only passing through the circle, doesn't detect outliers like the single points at the bottom of the picture).

I am looking for a **better way to detect large heaps of points** like in the picture. It should not remove false positives (of perhaps 5 or 10 points, these aggregations don't matter to me). Also, it should not simplify the rest of the track!

**Edit:** The result in given example should look like this:
[image]

Comment: +1 for the visualization, although I think the question could be improved by explaining your own considerations a bit more specifically. Otherwise this seems to be a bit broad.

Comment: Working opensource algorithm here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480434/simplification-optimization-of-gps-track/36195571#36195571

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first step would be to investigate the speeds implied by the 'movements' of your stationary car and the changes in altitude.  If either of these changes too quickly or too slowly (you'll have to decide the thresholds here) then you can probably conclude that they are due to the GPS jitter.

What information, other than position at time, does your GPS device report ?

**EDIT** (after OP's comment)

The problem is to characterise part of the log as 'car moving' and part of the log as 'car not moving but GPS location jittering'.  I suggested one approach, Benjamin suggested another.  If speed doesn't discriminate accurately enough, try acceleration.  Try rate of change of heading. If none of these simple  approaches work, I think it's time for you to break out your stats textbooks and start figuring out autocorrelation of random processes and the like.  At this point I quietly slink away ...

Comment: That's a good point and I thought of that too. A threshold for trying could be 3 kph. Besides time and position, the logger gives only information about calculated data (speed, acceleration and heading). It's a stripped NMEA RMC, no information about signal quality or satellite data.

Comment: I checked the gpx files: The jittering contains speeds over 10 kph, so this method doesn't work! :(

Answer (score 2):

Similarly to High Performance Mark's answer, you could look for line intersections that happen within a short number of points. When driving on a road, the route of the last n points rarely intersects with itself, but it does in your stationary situation because of the jitter. A single intersection could be a person doubling-back or circling around a block, but multiple intersections should be rarer. The angle of intersection will also be sharper for the jitter case.

Comment: +1: I like this answer because it suggests a fast, immediately implementable solution that would probably work. Bravo.

Comment: As regards 'false positive' intersections - looking at the point spacing, I would say that the time resolution is on the order of one second. To repeatedly self-intersect your path on that time scale you would have to be a dog chasing your own tail.

Answer (score 0):

What is the data interval of the GPS Points, it seems that these are in seconds. There may be one other way to add to the logic previously mentioned.

> sum_of_distance(d0,d1,d2....dn)>=80% of sum_of_distance(d0,dn)

This 0 to n th value can iterate in smaller and larger chunks, as the traveled distance within that range will not be much. So, you can iterate over may be 60 points of data initially, and within that data iterate in 10 number of data in each iteration.