# Gps Track Detection Algorithm

Tags: java, android, algorithm, gps

I am working on an Android app that will record (with GPS) the tracks that a user rides on their dirt bike. After finishing a ride I would like to be able to analyse this data and find the tracks that were ridden.

I will define a track as the travelled area between two intersections. An intersection being two or more points that are close enough to each other to be classified as one point. Obviously I need to decide on some sort of threshold for this.

Obviously I can do this with brute force checking every point against every other point but I think there must be a more efficient approach.

Any ideas on a better way?

Thanks Guys.

Comment: Working opensource algorithm here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480434/simplification-optimization-of-gps-track/36195571#36195571

Answer (score 1):

[Kalman filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter) is frequently used to reject error (noise) points and to simplify GPS tracks and estimate real trajectories. Wiki page looks rather complex, so it would be nice to find some practical articles about track filtering.

Answer (score 0):

To be practical:

1. the GPS points must be in the order of your ridding, so you only need to check some continuous points to be a intersection.
2. for every point, make it the center of a circle, see how many points stands in the circle, then you can combine these points into one intersection.
3. the generated intersections will also be in the order of your ridding.

Comment: How would this work in the situation where you come across the same intersection from a different track later in the ride?

Comment: @user1381573 if the points are (a1, a2, b1, b2, c1, c2, a1, a2), the generated intersections will be (a, b, c, a). think (a1, a2), (b1, b2) and (c1, c2) are both very close to each other.

Answer (score 0):

For on-the-run stream like track simplification (I call it "streamplification") is: you keep a small buffer of the points the GPS sensor gives you, each time a GPS point is added to the buffer (elevation included) you calculate the max XTD (cross track distance) of all the points in the buffer to the line segment that unites the first point with the (newly added) last point of the buffer. If the point with the greatest XTD violates your max tolerated XTD error (25m has given me great results) then you cut the buffer at that point, register it as a selected point to be appended to the streamplified track, trim the trailing part of the buffer up to that cut point, and keep going. At the end of the track the last point of the buffer is also added/flushed to the solution. This algorithm is lightweight enough that it runs on an AndroidWear smartwatch and gives optimal output regardless of if you move slow or fast, or stand idle at the same place for a long time. The ONLY thing that maters is the SHAPE of your track. You can go for many minutes/kilometers and, as long as you are moving in a straight line (a corridor within +/- tolerated XTD error deviations) the streamplify algorithm will only output 2 points: those of the exit form last curve and entry on next curve.

Check this Q&A also
[Simplification / optimization of GPS track](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480434/simplification-optimization-of-gps-track)